# Android drawable only have image for one dpi

Tags: android, android-drawable

If I only have image for `xhdpi`, and I don't want to create scaled images, I want android automatically scale down when screen density is lower than `xhdpi` and scale up when screen density is higher than `xhdpi`. How can I achieve this?

I tried create `drawable-xhdpi` folder, and put the image into it. However, in layout editor, the image doesn't show up, after I change the folder name to `drawable-xxhdpi`, the image appears, but too small.

I guess the preview device is `xxhdpi` so it can't use images in `xhdpi`, I wonder if same thing happens in real devices?

If so, how can I use only one dpi image and let the system automatically scaled to other dpi?

Edit: I forgot to mention it is used as bitmap item in a layer list used in launch screen `windowBackground`, since app haven’t launched yet, it can’t run java code there.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your drawable in `res/drawable/` folder (without any density qualifier) and then use the [`ImageView.ScaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I forgot to mention, it is used as bitmap item in windowBackground in launch screen, so I can’t run java code there

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use one image that scales well across different densities and screen sizes, then SVG(Scaleable Vector Graphics) is the way to go.That scales pretty good and you wont see pixellation.

Here is all you need to know about Vector Drawables

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#when